# Efficiently Creating Multiple Variables Using apply in R

Tags: database, r, variables, apply, lapply

I have a data frame DF which contains numerous variables. Each variable is present twice because I am conducting an analysis of "couples".

Among others, DF has a series of indicators of diversity :

```
 DF$div1.1, DF$div2.1, .... , DF$divN.1, DF$div.1.2, ..., DF$divN.2
```

Similarly, it has a series of indicators of another characteristic:

```
 DF$char1.1, DF$char2.1, .... , DF$charM.1, DF$char.1.2, ..., DF$charM.2
```

Here's a link to an example of DF: http://shorttext.com/5d90dd64

Each time the ".1", ".2" stand for the couple member considered.

**My goal:** 
For each indicator  divI and charJ, I want to create another variable `DF$divchar` that takes the value `DF$divI.1` when `DF$charJ.1`>`DF$charJ.2`; and `DF$divI.2` when `DF$charJ.1`<`DF$charJ.2`.

Here is the solution I came up with, it seems somehow very intricate and sometimes behaves in strange ways:

1. I created a series of binary variables that take the value one if `DF$charJ.1`>`DF$charJ.2`. The are stored under `DF$CharMax.1`.
   Here's how I created it:

   ```
   DF$CharMax.1 <- as.data.frame(
       sapply(1:length(nam), 
           function(n) 
           as.numeric(DF[names(DF)==names.1[n]] 
           >DF[names(DF)==names.2[n]])
               ))
   ```
2. I created the function `BinaryExtract`:

   ```
   BinaryExtract <- function(var1, var2, extract) {var1*extract +var2*(1-extract)}
   ```
3. I created the matrix `NameFull` that contains all the possible combinations of `div` and `char`, separated with `"YY"`

   ```
   NameFull <- sapply(c("div1",...,"divN")
       , function(nam) paste(nam, names(DF$YMax.1), sep="YY")
   ```
4. And then I create all my variables:

   ```
    DF[, as.vector(NameFull)] <-   lapply(as.vector(NameFull),   function(e) 
       BinaryExtract(DF[,paste0(unlist(strsplit(e,"YY"))[1],".1")] 
       , DF[, paste0(unlist(strsplit(e,"YY"))[1],".1")]
       , DF$charMax.1[unlist(strsplit(e,"YY"))[2]]))
   ```

**My Problem**

A. It looks like a very complicated solution for something that simple. What am I missing?

B. Moreover, when I print DF, just typing `DF` in the command window,  I do not see the variables `NameFull`. They seem to appear with the names of `char`. 
Here's what I get: http://shorttext.com/5d9102c

Similarly, I have tried to change all their names to get rid of the "YY" and it does not seem to work:

```
   names(DF[, as.vector(NameFull)]) <- as.vector(c("div1",...,"divN"), sapply(, function(nam) 
    paste(nam, names(DF$YMax.1), sep=".")))
```

When I look at `names(DF)`, I keep getting the old names with the `"YY"`

However, I do get a result if I explicitly call for them

```
 > DF[,"divIYYcharJ"]
```

I would really appreciate any suggestion, comment and explanation. I am quite new to R ad was more used to Stata. I feel there is something deeply inefficient here. Thanks

Comment: [reproducible example reproducible example reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Just transform your data.frame to long format. The problem becomes very simple then. You should read [Tidy Data](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf).

Comment: `apply(df, 1, function(x) {sapply(seq(1,length(x),2), function(x) {ifelse((x[i] > x[i+1]), x[1], x[2])})})` Try that, rowwise operation on the columns within each row. Assuming the column for each pair is right next to each other. You also want to make sure that your df contains only the columns for characteristics.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. @Roland I thought about reshaping, but since I have many many observations (21800 couples), I am afraid that the reshaping will take forever and that after that, **all** operations are going to take very long

Comment: @Doon_Bogan If you use package data.table, reshaping should be almost instantaneous.

Comment: @RichardScriven: I added the reproducible example, if you also have any other suggestions. Thanks for the comment